# Favicon no funciona al redireccionar una página de github-pages a mi propio dominio

Tags: html, github, github-pages

Buen dia, tengo una pagina montada en github pages: http://ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/

Si se abre la pagina desde ese link, el favicon funciona perfectamente, pero compre un dominio en goDaddy para redireccionar esa pagina y enmascarándola para usar mi dominio: [ludicultura.com](http://ludicultura.com) y ahí es donde no funciona el favicon.

(Ambos links están funcionando, así que los puedes probar.)

Intente la opcion de agregar un "?" al final del "href":

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico?">
```

Y también la intente cambiando mi icono a png:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

Pero nada funciona, ¿que estará pasando?

Codigo fuente y todos los cambios del repositorio con mi proyecto:
https://github.com/ludicultura/ludiweb

Answer (score 1):

Creo que son varios problemas relacionados con la ruta que estás usando y/o la forma en que apuntas tu dominio.

- En primer lugar estás usando un `iframe` para enmascarar la página. En la página que llamas al `iframe`, **no existe** ninguna marca de favicon. Esto es lo que ve un navegador al visitar el sitio `ludicultura.com`:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>ludicultura.com</title>

  </head>
  <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
    <frame src="http://ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/" frameborder="0" />
    <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
  </frameset>

  <!-- pageok -->
  <!-- 01 -->
  <!-- -->
  </html>%
  ```

  Podrías usar un *alias*, llamado CNAME para que tu sitio funcionara mejor.
- En segundo lugar, la generación de tu página estática (**no indicas *cómo* estás generando tu sitio**) no funciona. Esto es lo que se ve al consultar el código fuente de `ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/`:

  ```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/favicon.ico">
  ```

### Conclusión

1. Usa un nombre canónico, alias o CNAME en lugar del `iframe`.
2. Corrige el problema con tu generador de página o escribe directamente la URL de tu sitio.

Comment: 1. No configuré nada en los dns por qué goDaddy ya tiene una opción de enmascarar la página automáticamente, con el CNAME será suficiente? 
2. Para escribir directamente la url solo cambio el "site.baseurl" a "site.http://ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/" ??

Comment: 1. La redirección con CNAME es mejor. 2. Sustituye `{{ site.baseurl }}` por la URL completa (incluyendo `http://` de tu sitio).

Answer (score 1):

El código debe ser este.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"></link>
```

Además noté otro problema, el `favicon.ico` de tu repositorio en **GitHub** tiene otro problema, que tiene dimensiones de *31x31*, cuando debería ser *16x16*.

Yo recomendaría que subas un archivo **png** de 16x16 en el mismo directorio donde está el *favicon.ico* y luego lo cambies por este código, no hace falta aclarar si el `type` es ico o png, es decir, el formato del archivo.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png"></link>
```